# Wordpress not letting me save Featured Images

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to attach a featured image to a post, but after I click the "Use as Featured Image" button, it changes to "saving" and then just stays there.

Normally it only takes a second or so.

I've looked into memory issues but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Is there anything else that seems to cause this?

I'm testing on the basic 2011 theme and no plugins and the newest Wordpress.

Chrome IS giving me some kind of error, but I don't know how to interpret it.

```
POST *website*/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php  load-scripts.php:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send load-scripts.php:4
f.extend.ajax load-scripts.php:4
f.each.f.(anonymous function) load-scripts.php:4
WPSetAsThumbnail load-scripts.php:6
onclick
```

Answer (score 0):

**Troubleshooting:**

Have you updated your WP installation recently? It may be possible that your browser still holds an older version of the admin scripts which creates the error.

Try clearing your cache and try again:
http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32050